# How to change the message content

Tags: ios, push-notification, localnotification

[Alert Message for pushnotification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBKE6.png)

How can i change the message content for my app.

[Plist changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dathB.png)

Answer (score 1):

At first, title of alert message (Dark black text), you cannot change. IT’s an default message set by Apple. But Message of this alert (Below-Light texts), you can change.

For that you can set key `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` or `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key in `Info.plist` as per your requirement and you can set their string value whatever you want to display.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried adding NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key in information property list  and i added strings. But i there is no changes when running as new file.

Comment: See screenshots in my answer. And please once again check in your app, if anything is wrong.

Comment: I can't find why changes are not reflecting in app. please find updated screenshot.